# Convert Mongoose object to particular json schema(object)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose

i have a requirement, when I am fetching data from MongoDB and using mongoose as an ORM. now the data that i fetch from DB, i keep in mongoose object. I do not want to send back all the information as response to client. I have a specific JSON response schema template. i want to convert the mongoose object to this  particular JSON object and then send the response.

Comment: pass in a filter to your `.find()` method that only retrieves the properties that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a filter to your .find() method that only retrieves the properties that you want.

```
collection.find({}).select('name age');
```

If you have large datasets, you can go the opposite route and exclude the fields you don't want

```
collection.find({}).select('-created -createdBy');
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But my response structure is pretty big.  So it wouldn't be a good design to use select(). Also in my response I have array of $ref. Its a big structure. I am thinking to create a json schema template and then just covert the mongoose obj to json. will it work and is this a good design?? i need suggestions.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how to exclusion instead of including.  I'm not a fan of ODM because it's an extra layer that I don't think is needed.  Let the DB give you the data you need and don't worry about massaging it.